# Login to gmail account through another website

Tags: java, html, servlets, authentication, gmail

I was wondering if it is possible to login to the Gmail account through a different site. I would like to use Servlet to send a request to the google's auth server to log in to Gmail and the response should be generated as answer or redirected to the logged in gmail account. As far as I know, Google uses OAuth2 for authentication.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want to log in to a Gmail account to send/see emails then you can use the [JavaMail](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/javamail_api/) API